# Django ManyToManyField and Form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm writing my first Django App and I have two classes in my `models.py` file, Ingredient and Meal. A food has many ingredients and you're suppose to be able to set the quantity of each ingredient in the meal, so that's my `models.py`:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='Recipe_Ingredient')

class Recipe_Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    UNITY_CHOICES = (
        ('g', 'Gram(s)'),
        ('kg', 'Kilogram(s)'),
        ('l', 'Liter(s)'),
        ('cl', 'Centiliter(s)'),
    )

    quantityUnit = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=UNITY_CHOICES,
        default='g',
)
```

The Recipe_Ingrent class is the ManyToMany associate table to store the quantity.

The problem here is that I don't know how to use Forms in this case. I have a template `meal_edit.html` that calls a django form in `form.py`.

To add an ingredient my form would be simple, like this:

```
from .models import Ingredient

class IngridientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ('name',)
```

So, how am I suppose to make a form that will create a recipe with multiple ingredients and a quantity for each of those?

Comment: Have you considered using a formset?

Comment: Hi @Bott0610, this is my first django project, I didn't know about formset, but I read it's used to work with multiple forms on the same page. I believe in my case I would need only one form on my page, so formset wouldn't be much help, correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Create an UpdateView for you model in views.py, you can use form classes and specify your form, or you can also create an instance of your form and pass it to the template in your context_data and activate it using form.as_p

Comment: Hi @TheodoreHowell, I am doing that form the IngredientForm, using form.as_p, my question is how to write the form to create a Meal with multiple ingredients and each one associated with a quantity.

Answer (score 1):

[Django formsets:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/)

Essentially, each Ingredient would be a form within your larger form (although, you would have only one `<form` tag in your template. For example:

models.py:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Recipe_Ingredient(models.Model):
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Not sure what this is, but I'll leave that to you
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    UNITY_CHOICES = (
        ('g', 'Gram(s)'),
        ('kg', 'Kilogram(s)'),
        ('l', 'Liter(s)'),
        ('cl', 'Centiliter(s)'),
    )

    quantityUnit = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=UNITY_CHOICES,
        default='g',
    )
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from your_app import models

class IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Recipe_Ingredient
        fields = ['ingredient', 'quantity', 'quantityUnit']


IngredientFormset = forms.inlineformset_factory(models.Meal, models.Recipe_Ingredient, form=IngredientForm, extra=2)
```

views.py:

```
from your_app import forms, models

class YourMealModelView():

    model = models.Meal

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            context_data['ingredients_formset'] = forms.IngredientFormset(
                self.request.POST,
                instance=self.object,   # as in your Meal object
                prefix='ingredients'
            )
        else:
            context_data['ingredients_formset'] = forms.IngredientFormset(
                instance=self.object, prefix='ingredients'
            )

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # You can manipulate the formsets here as well:
        context_data = self.get_context_data()
        ingredients_formset = context_data['ingredients_formset']

        meal = form.save()

        for i_form in ingredients_formset:
            delete = i_form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE')
            if delete:
                i_form.instance.delete()
                continue

            # do stuff and save
            ingredient_recipe = i_form.save(commit=False)
            ingredient_recipe.meal = meal
            ingredient_recipe.save()
```

template:

```
<form id="meal_form">
    {% for field in form.fields %}
        {{ field.label }}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}

    <table>
        <thead>
            {{ ingredients_formset.management_form }}
            <tr>
                <th>Ingredient</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Units</th>
                <th>Delete?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for i_form in ingredients_formset.forms %}
                <tr id="{{ i_form.prefix }}">
                    {{ i_form.id }}
                    <td>{{ i_form.ingredient }}</td>
                    <td>{{ i_form.quantity }}</td>
                    <td>{{ i_form.quantityUnit }}</td>
                    <td>{% if i_form.instance.pk %}{{i_form.DELETE %}{% endif %}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Of course, there is a bunch of stuff I left out like adding new items to the formset with javascript, how to handle new meals vs editing existing ones, and what Django View to use etc, but this gives you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you tell me exactly what's going on in the view? I don't really get it.

Comment: @Luc which aspect of it needs clarification?